# Eclipse scrambling image files

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Just downloaded the ADT eclipse bundle from the Google/Android page.

I imported a couple projects from my old workspace on another computer.

I go to res/drawable and when I click on any of the png files the editor screen opens them as a bunch of jumbled nonsense and weird symbols. When I open the png files directly from their folder in the file manager all of the png files look fine.

I'm running Mint 17 KDE with Eclipse JUNO.
This is what the editor preview looks like:

[image]

Comment: Probably because you're opening a binary file in an editor and it's not opening in an image viewer. Try right clicking and pressing "Open with..."

Comment: Have you tried the option on right click: open with system editor?

Comment: @MartinFrank . That was the solution. How do I set it to always make png files open with the system editor by default?

Comment: T@RyPope seems to have it.  My eclipse opens images into the gallery app.

Comment: i^m glad that helped out, but to be fair, @RyPope had the same idea ^^ so we were **both** right ^^